# TextView Size is different on different device

Tags: android, textview

I have given programmatically 200 size(Width) for text view. Have tested on some devices but on oppo X9006 the size displayed is very less as I compare with other devices so text overlaps on this device. May be I think its because of ppi of device and this oppo device is off high density so textview is displayed small in size. Am I correct ?? If not then what could be the reason behind this?

And how can I make it similar for all devices. Do I need to get ppi of devices and accordingly set size of TextView? How can I do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post some screenshots and your layout files so we can help you

Comment: Text should always be set with `sp`. Are you not doing that?

Comment: I am programmatically  setting textview width.

Comment: Sorry, because of security reasons I cant paste screenshots here @Rosario

Answer (score -1):

There should be warning(s) in the layout file(s) saying that you should use `sp` instead of `dp` for text in order to keep the same text size on different density devices.

**EDIT**

You can set text size programmatically.

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

In dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textsize">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Or

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textsize);
```

Comment: Please read before commenting. I clearly mentioned I am creating TextView Programmatically. When you set text view width its just an int value not SP or DP

Comment: @unflagged.destination Read my edit to see how to set it programmatically.

Comment: Please read my question. Its not about textview text size, Its about textview width.. and also to make you correct its about different width shown in different devices. May be the reason is ppi of device, That is what I am asking. And you are giving me answers of setting textsize.